# Get total, not unique, number of cracked passwords from John the Rippers output?

Tags: password-cracking, john-the-ripper

I am giving John the Ripper a file that may contain duplicate hashes, and get output like this:

```
2g 0:00:00:01  1.600g/s 3.200p/s 3.200c/s 70227C/s 123456789..abc123
```

Which represents the total number of *unique* passwords cracked over time. Is there a way to get *total* number of passwords (which contains duplicate password counts as well) cracked over time from John's output?

Comment: You say `file that may contain duplicate hashes`. Do you really mean duplicate hashes - that is, same password and same hash? Or do you mean duplicate passwords with different hashes?

Comment: I mean same password with the same hash

Comment: Why don't you strip those out before running the tool? (Duplicate hashes likely means a weak password storage mechanism as salts should make hashes unique.)

Comment: Because multiple people can have the same password. Frequency analysis of a given password corpus has significant research value.

Answer (score 2):

"NoLoaderDupeCheck" attribute in the john.conf file is what i was looking for.

Comment: FYI: It is acceptable to mark your own answer as the right answer.